# woocommerce_email_attachments hook with empty $order argument in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, object, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

The person building a WP site for me is stuck for some time now with this problem. He needs to attach some custom PDF files into the order confirmation mail. He uses `woocommerce_emails_attach_downloadables` function to do that. For some reason that function is getting called with the `$order` parameter being empty.

Here is the code he uses :

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_attachments', 'attach_order_notice', 10, 3 );
function attach_order_notice ( $attachments, $email_id, $order )
{

//

   // Only for "New Order" email notification (for admin)
   if( $email_id == 'customer_on_hold_order' ){

      $pdf_options = array(
//       "source_type" => 'html',
//       "source" => '<html>hello</html>',
         "source_type" => 'url',
         "source" => 'http://tt.dev.co.il/checkout/order-received/757/?key=wc_order_5bce0e5ba39b8',
         "action" => 'save',
         "save_directory" => get_template_directory() .'/pdfs',
         "file_name" => 'print-pdf'. json_encode($order) .'.pdf');


//    phptopdf($pdf_options);




      $attachments[] = get_template_directory() . '/pdfs/print-pdf.pdf';
   }
   return $attachments;
}
```

**So my questions are:**  
What are those cases ? 
What can cause `$order` to be passed as empty ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your developer has been using maybe [this woocommerce official snippet](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/email-faq/#section-14) *(That is outdated as it is 3 years old)* and it uses `woocommerce_email_attachments` filter hook.

This filter hook is defined:

- one time *(1)* in `WC_Email` class *(with the `$order` argument)*
- three times *(3)* in `WC_emails` Class *(**without** the `$order` argument)*

> So the `WC_Order` Object `$order` is only defined in `WC_Email` class as third argument.

That means that this outdated official code **need to be tweaked** as follow:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_attachments', 'woocommerce_emails_attach_downloadables', 10, 3 );
function woocommerce_emails_attach_downloadables( $attachments, $email_id, $order ) {
    // Avoiding errors and problems
    if ( ! is_a( $order, 'WC_Order' ) || ! isset( $email_id ) ) {
        return $attachments;
    }

    // ===>  Your custom code goes Here  <===

    return $attachments;
}
```

This should work avoiding problems.

> So as you are asking, this hook is also used on the following specific product notifications **with really different hook arguments**:
>
> - On **"Low stock" notification** *(with `'low_stock'` and `$product` as 2nd & 3rd arguments)*
> - On **"No stock" notification** *(with `'no_stock'` and `$product` as 2nd & 3rd arguments)*
> - On **"Backorder" notification** *(with `'backorder'` and `$args` as 2nd & 3rd arguments)*
>
> So here the 2nd argument is the stock status `$stock_status` and the 3rd argument is the `WC_Product` object `$product` *(or an array `$args`)*.

**Then In those 3 notifications, the `$order` object doesn't exist** as it can be a `WC_Product` Object, an array, an empty array, or null.

Comment: thanks ! I think the answer is very close to what you said. I updated the original question with the real code. Could you see what is wrong there ? I see that he uses a different filter than the one mentioned

Comment: Just to better understand the answer : the same hook is called a number of times for the same order ? Some of the times with a set A of params and the other times with a somewhat different set of params ? And in the hook the code needs to "understand" which type of a call this one is ? Right ?

Comment: @LouisShraga The hook is called on other notifications as product Low stock, No stock, Backorder… And it's called on all Order notifications, if you don't restrict it to a specific `$email_id`. In your code it's restricted to `$email_id = 'customer_on_hold_order'` so it's used on Customer on Hold Order email notification… If you like/want you could please also upvote this answer. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Thanks, do you know and/or can point me please to the documentation (i just cant find it) where it says if $order is set for a call in case of customer_on_hold emailId

Comment: @LouisShraga There is no a specific documentation… When an order is set ta a specific order status, it will trigger the related email notification, if it's set and defined… You can explore the source code of each woocommerce classes  starting with [WC_Email](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Email.html) For each class you have the order status transitions that is triggering an email.